# getConstants in React native

Tags: java, react-native

I am trying to learn native development in React Native

I was going through [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) and it says

> An optional method called getConstants returns the constant values
>   exposed to JavaScript. Its implementation is not required but is very
>   useful to key pre-defined values that need to be communicated from
>   JavaScript to Java in sync

with following snippet

```
@Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return constants;
  }
```

From the above defination, I was able to make out that this pass constant one time use information from Javascript to java (such as api key)

To confirm, I went to [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) repo.

There I saw they have used it like this

```
@Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put("legalNotice", "This license information is displayed in Settings > Google > Open Source on any device running Google Play services.");
    return constants;
  }
```

and it isn't consuming anything passed.

So can someone please explain me the above definition in slightly more details? and what is it use (`getConstants()` method)?

Answer (score 0):

`getConstants` defines constant that can be consumed in JavaScript world. It is useful when you want to let JavaScript specify some parameters.

Example from react native doc:

```java
  @ReactMethod
  public void show(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put("SHORT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    constants.put("LONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return constants;
  }
```

This will create a constant `SHORT` with value of `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` (integer). so on JavaScript side they can use the constant like

```js
ToastModule.show('message', ToastModule.SHORT);
```

This way JavaScript doesn't have to know actual integer value of Toast.LENGTH_SHORT and instead use the constant exposed by native module (ToastExample.SHORT).